# Show and Hide ActivityIndicator using SDWebImageDownloader

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview, sdwebimage

I am loading image using SDWebImageDownloader classes on every button click in my view.

```
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = mainImage.center;
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[imgView setImageWithURL:url   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderLarge.png"] options:0 andResize:CGSizeMake(mainImage1.frame.size.width,imgview.frame.size.height) withContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[imgView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

I am not getting where to remove activityIndicator

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following block.. Its more effective and it works for me...

```
[imgView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"] success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    } failure:^(NSError *error){  
     //do any additional tasks if its failure
        }];
```